# How to filter, select and interact with a reactive data frame without user inputs? Shiny, Rmarkdown and Flexdashboard

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a problem since a few days with the selection or filtering of a reactive data frame, all this in the context of the development of a dashboard in Rmarkdown, Flexdashboard and Shiny.

The data frame is a web service of the type:

`www.somewebpage.com/project1/service.py?parameter1=2020&parameter2=ABC`

Where the user selects the parameters (**parameter1** and **parameter2**) and presses a button to execute the call to the web service, returning a JSON that I subsequently transformed it into a data frame.

Now my question is.

> I have a reactive data frame, it is a function more than a data frame, how can I filter or select variables from the reactive data frame, but only in the code, **without any user input?**

Below is an example code of how I create the reactive data frame.

```
myData <- reactive({
        input$params # Action Button
        
        serv <- "www.somewebpage.com/project1/service.py?parameter1=2020&parameter2=ABC"
        dataURL <- isolate(urltools::param_set(urls = serv, key = "parameter1", value = input$parameter1))
        dataURL <- isolate(urltools::param_set(urls = dataURL, key = "parameter2", value = input$parameter2))
        resp <- httr::GET(dataURL)
        jsonRespText <- httr::content(resp, as = "text")
        jsonRespParsed <- httr::content(resp, as="parsed")
        df_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(jsonRespText)
        modJson <- jsonRespParsed$Data
        
        dfCol <- modJson %>% bind_rows %>% dplyr::select(var1,
                                                         var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8)  
})
```

In the code provided above, I show how to create the reactive data frame called `"myData"`.

> How can I filter or select variables from the `"myData"` object?

For example, I want to show only some variables from `"myData"` in a Data Table:

```
renderDT({
  A <-  DT::datatable(data = myData() , extensions = "Buttons", 
                      options = list(
                        columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(2,3,4))), 
                        pageLength = 10,
                        searchHighlight = TRUE, 
                        language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json'),
                        buttons = list("copy", "print", list(
                          extend = "collection",
                          buttons = c("csv","excel","pdf"),
                          text = "Descargar"
                        )),
                        dom = "Bftip"
                      ))
  A
})
```

And what I get is shown in the image, I only want to show some variables, not all.

[image: Data Table Output]

I will remain alert if you need more information from me.

Thank you very much.

**EDITED**

Partially solved!

I'm **still looking at how to filter a reactive data frame**, but to select, simply specify the columns as I show in the code.

```
renderDT({
  A <-  DT::datatable(data = myData()[,c(2,3,4)]) # Selecting columns 2, 3 and 4.
  A
})
```

Comment: If you can get what you want with the select, can't you just use logical expressions to filter as well? unless you need a complex filter.